# Android fragment slide out animation not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a two fragments top and bottom . On swipe down gesture, bottom fragment is hidden and on swipe up, it's shown again. swipe up slide up animation is working, but not the swipe down animation during swipe down.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/baseLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container1Parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:
    str = "Swipe Up";
 getSupportFragmentManager()
 .beginTransaction()
 .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom,
 R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom).show(bottomFragment)
    .commit();
   break;
```

### abc_slide_in_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="50%p"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="0" />
```

### abc_slide_out_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="50%p" />
```

**NOTE** : Bottom fagment takes up only 20 % of total screen

Comment: i think animation actually happens, but as the view size is less, apparently can't see the results, Someone tell me is this what actually happening??

Comment: @RaviBhatt, Top fragment is a list with loaded contents. i don't understand `after animation the top surface of view is stick to the top of the screen`, can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. so removing my previous comment. And yes it may be possible that your view size is less so you can not see the animation.